# Scoped Styling in Django

Tags: css, django, scope, styling

My base.html

```
     ...
    <body>
        {% include 'parts/navbar.html' %}
        <div>This is the base content html file</div>
        {% block content %} 
        {% endblock %} 
        {% include 'parts/footer.html' %}
     </body>
     ...
```

my navbar:

```
<div>NAV</div>
```

my footer:

```
<div>Footer</div>

<style>
  div {
    color: blueviolet;
  }
</style>
```

The footer style applies also to the nav-div which i don't want.
Is scoped styling in Django possible or do i have to use line-styles or some engine etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django does not handle that.
You can use https://sass-lang.com/guide and nest your CSS.

Comment: Thanks, than I'll use an ID or a class as workaround, maybe if the project gets bigger i'll give sass a try.